# Chartjs bar chart multiple tooltip coming on single chart

Tags: jquery, chart.js

Chart js bar chart on single bar multiple tooltip coming . I am using custom tooltip

[image]

[image]

In image 1 and image 2 same bar two tooltip coming

Comment: It depends on your mouse position in your element

Comment: Yes i know but on same bar two tooltip conflict

Comment: you can share your relevant code plz